# Easiest way to make a wizard that takes input and generates a document

Tags: ms-word, automation, report, wizard

In our Project we have a lot of People generating many plans and report (word and pdf) documents. Problem is that they don't get to follow same standards even after sharing a template.

What I wish. is making a program/solution something that does following;

1- Select the type of document u want (e.g. Status Report or Test Plan)
2- Based on the report u chose, it offers u some text Box to Write ur text
3- Next NeXT and after keep filling the necessary Fields - it generates a Word document from the input

So any opinion on how to and what tool to use to achieve this in quickest way possible?

Im not a Developer but I am have some basic Programming skills and knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used MS Access.

Made a Table with the fields I am interested in having
Using form Wizard, connected them to a very interactive form
Generated document in certain formats using the report wizard of MS Access